# Should we re-use the migration scripts created by the dev server on the production server?

Tags: django, reusability, database-migration, django-south

I am using South for database migration for a Django project. And I was wondering if it is a good idea to commit the migration scripts that were generated by my dev server to the repository & then reusing it on the production server?

Comment: I do, and haven't run into any issues.

Comment: That's in fact the very procedure you're supposed to follow. One could even say that's the whole purpose of migrations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  That is the point of migrations to allow you to develop and test database schema changes and then deploy in test and production in a reproducible way.

I wouldn't consider it reuse so much as developed and tested in development and then deployed on production.

Make sure you also develop and test backward migrations to ensure you can retreat.